# Link not clickable because ::Before and ::After

Tags: html, css

I wanted to implement an (I think) awesome looking drawing border around some content but that requires the use of `::before` and `::after`. This makes my link inside the content element unable to use.

Down here I succeeded in recreating the problem I'm talking about. You can see that the link is not clickable anymore because of the `::before` and `::after`. When I remove it would be clickable but I would like to keep my border.

```css
.text::before, .text::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum 123</p>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link</a>
</div>
```

For people who want to take a look at the border (maybe that would be possible without `::after` and `::before`. My site is [www.tdcdkhd.com](http://www.tdcdkhd.com). The border/ content I'm talking about is the one in the slide-show banner on the homepage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first easy solution is to use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
}

.text::before,
.text::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum 123</p>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link</a>
</div>
```

Or play with z-index like this:

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.text::before,
.text::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum 123</p>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, I couldn't find it for like 1 hour searching but got an answer in like 5 minuts, I should have asked earlier. Thank!

Comment: @Temani Afif It's very interesting, I've never heard about this property, absolutely new information for me, thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy i added another way with z-index ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks but I think I'm fine with the `pointer-event` one already. But if someday I need to change it up I will try the `z-index` way ;)

Comment: @Temani Afif by the way I had some problems with `z-index: -1;` for absolutely positioned pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`. I added background-image for part of parent div using `:before` or `:after` and it worked fine everywhere but not on iPad.

Comment: @Heidel did you also add z-index:0 to parent ? this will prevent the issue

Comment: @Temani Afif Nope, I didn't know about this tip, I need to try it, it's my current project right now ;)

Comment: Great,  pointer-events: none helped a lot

Answer (score 4):

Try applying `pointer-events: none` to `::after` and `::before` pseudo elements like below

```
.text::before, .text::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to link properties

```
.text a {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I also thought that would be the solution (should have said in my question I already tried that) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I've checked it in Google Chrome console, it works.

Comment: @Heidel it works in the simplified case but he need to consider his full code to correctly use it .. if you check his site you will see that the link is inside a `p` element so he need to apply this to the p ... the idea is correct but he need to know where to correctly apply it

Comment: @Temani Afif I used his code from the question, I didn't check code on his website.